# Is it possible to edit the Python float method, to round every float output without specifying?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, floating-point, overriding

UPDATED to reflect a better question:

Not that this is good practice, just curious if anyone knows <s>how to</s>  **if its possible** to override the Python Float <s>function</s> **type** such that it rounds every output without having to do any individual operations, **such that if you are in a class, every number that gets returned is rounded off.**

For example:

```
class example():    
    def float():
       #modify to return value for any float to round to 2 places
    a = 5 * 7.567 #= 37.835
    print(a) # a's value as 37.84
```

NOTE: I don't think this is possible. Just curious if anyone knows for sure, or has a hack for getting this kind of functionality.

Comment: `float` is not a function, it is a type.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to not mess up with builtin types. Instead I can recommend you to read about Decimals which will grant you full control over precision.

Python2 (https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html)
Python3.7 (https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/decimal.html)

Decimal is standard library so it's always there for you!